# How do I format my output in Java for this specific instance to add spaces?

Tags: java, encoding

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish. When you enter numbers in this format

```
1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 6
```

you get

```
1 1 2 2 3 2 4 2 5 1 6 1
```

In other words it tells you how many of each string you have. The problem is I can't figure out how to get there to be spaces in between the output. This is the code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunLengthEncoding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sequence of integers separated by spaces:");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input: " + input);
        String c = " ";

        char ch = 0;
        int count = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++)
            if (input.charAt(x) != ' ') {
                if (ch == input.charAt(x)) {
                    count = count + 1;

                } else {
                    c = c + ch;
                    if (count != 1) {
                        c = c + count;
                    }

                    ch = input.charAt(x);
                    count = 1;
                }
            }

        c = c + ch;

        if (count != 1) {
            c = c + count;
        }

        System.out.println("encoder output:");
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println("\t");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere, where you update the String just add a space in between the original string and the count variable.

```
    c = c + " " +ch;
```

A few tweaks could be made to this code such as using StringBuilder or using the += operation rather than `c = c + " " + ch;` since that minimizes the line to only `c+=" " + ch;` As well as updating count using `count++`

Comment: Omg, thank you so much for not just the help but the suggestions for tweaking the code up too!

Answer (score 0):

I am using `StringBuilder` to build my output.  I am also using another variable to keep track of the last iteration's char to determine if I should keep counting or if I should move on to displaying counts.

This is my take on it:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunLengthEncoding  {
    private final static String BLANK_SPACE = " ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sequence of integers separated by spaces:");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input: " + input);
        StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();

        char ch = 0;
        int count = 1;
        char lastChar = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++) {
            // get first input in array
            ch = input.charAt(x);

            // if this is the first item we have fetched, there is no count yet - move on to the next input
            if( x == 0 ){
                lastChar = ch;
                continue;
            }

            if (ch != ' ') {
                if (ch == lastChar) {
                    count++;

                } else {
                    outputString.append(lastChar);
                    outputString.append(RunLengthEncoding.BLANK_SPACE);
                    outputString.append(count);
                    outputString.append(RunLengthEncoding.BLANK_SPACE);
                    count = 1;
                }
                lastChar = ch;
            }
        }
        outputString.append(lastChar);
        outputString.append(RunLengthEncoding.BLANK_SPACE);
        outputString.append(count);

        System.out.print("Encoder output: ");
        System.out.println(outputString);
    }
}
```

It produces this output:

> Enter a sequence of integers separated by spaces:1  2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 6
>   6 7
>
> Input: 1  2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 6 6 7
>
> Encoder output: 1 1 2 2 3 2 4 1 5
>   2 6 3 7 1